# What's a better way to use helper methods with will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm using the latest version of will_paginate with rails 3. I'd like to use out_of_bounds? to set the current page to the last page if the page parameter is higher than the last page. I found a way to do it like this:

```
people = People.all.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
@people = people.paginate(:page => (people.out_of_bounds? ? people.total_pages : params[:page))
```

The problem with this is that I have to call paginate twice. The first time to create a WillPaginate::Collection in order to use the out_of_bounds? and total_pages methods, and the second time to actually set the current page. I also need to do this with more actions so it's getting kinda out of hand. I can't use a before_filter or an after_filter, either (I don't think?). Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the best solution, but at least you can do the check before the second call to the method (I suppose that in most of the cases, the page parameter will be ok, so you wont have to call paginate twice):

```
people = People.all.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
@people = people.out_of_bounds? ? people.paginate(:page => people.total_pages) : people
```